# The PowerShell ISE sometimes behaves unpredictably after code changes are made

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, powershell-5.0

I'm using the PowerShell ISE (PS version 5.0).  If I run this code:

```
Write-Host "This"
```

It outputs:

```
This
```

If I modify the script like this:

```
Write-Host "That"
```

It outputs:

```
That
```

Great.  As expected.  Now, if I have this code:

```
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer

$Timer.Add_Tick(
{
    &{
    Write-Output "Here"
    $Form.Close()} | Write-Host 
})

$Timer.Interval = 3000
$Timer.start()
$result = $Form.ShowDialog()
```

It outputs:

```
Here
```

If I change *anything* in the script, e.g. `"Here"` to `"There"` or `$Timer.Interval = 3000` to `$Timer.Interval = 4000` and run it, it does two unexpected things: 1.) instead of showing the form for the proper duration of time, it briefly flashes it on the screen, and 2.) it outputs the original `Here` instead of `There`.  If I close the ISE and re-open it, the script runs as expected.

What is going on?

Comment: Well it looks like you're not disposing of the objects... so you're just creating lots of instances of the objects. Starting again from fresh clears out the in-memory objects

Comment: When you say "run it" - do you run the entire file/code snippet, or just the last part? You can't show a form after having closed it once, and unless you re-instantiate the `$timer`, the original event registration will still exist

Comment: @gvee -- so you're saying the ISE is holding onto the objects even after it stops?  Coming from .NET and Visual Studio with not much PS experience, I find this strange and unexpected.  I'm thinking "objects should automatically be disposed after it stops executing."

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen ^

Comment: @rory.ap - in VS it gets disposed of when the debugger is stopped, right? The equivalent in PS ISE is to close the session.

Comment: @gvee -- Yes that's right.  So you can see how I'd assume that when the red "stop" button at the top of the ISE changes to the green "run" button (as it does in VS), I'd assume everything was disposed/reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

- The **timer instance is created in the *session* scope**,

  - whether or not you run your script in the ISE,
  - and whether or not any variables that reference it are in scope.
- **Always dispose of a timer** (or at least disable it) to prevent it from generating more events.
- *Generally* - although that is *not* the cause of the problem at hand - be aware that **running a script in the ISE *implicitly dot-sources* it**, so that repeated executions run in the *same* scope, with variable values from previous ones *lingering*, which can lead to unexpected behavior.

---

Your code never disposes of (or disables) the timer, which therefore:

- stays alive for the entire *session*, whether or not a variable references it
- continues to *generate* events,
- but they only *fire* while a *form is being displayed*.

This explains your symptom: The *queued up, original* events fire *instantly* as soon as you display the form *again*.

The solution is to *dispose of the timer* once it has done its duty and fired the event (once):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer

$Timer.Add_Tick({
    & {
      Write-Output "Here"
      $Form.Close()
    } | Write-Host 
})

$Timer.Interval = 3000
$Timer.Start()
$result = $Form.ShowDialog()
$Timer.Dispose() # IMPORTANT: Dispose of the timer so it won't generate more events.
```

Even with the implicit sourcing behavior of the ISE described above, repeated invocations of this code work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with how variables in the ISE are still in memory even after the script ends. If you add

```
$Timer.Stop()
```

to the last line of the script then close and reopen the ISE it will work.

Comment: Running `$Timer.Stop()` is good advice, but the behavior is not related to the ISE.